# При регистрации пользователя TG bot выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, регистрация

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT_TOKEN')
name = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("baza.sql")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50), pass varchar(50)) ')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет сейчас тебя зарегистрируем! Введите своё имя')
    bot.register_message_handler(message, user_name)

def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_pass)

def user_pass(message):
    password = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect("baza.sql")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (name, password))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей', callback_data="users"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Регистрация прошла успешно!', reply_markup=markup)
    # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль')
    # bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_pass)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Ошибка:

```
> C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe \
> C:\PhytonProjects\python_beginners_course-main\pythonProject\.idea\Testobot1488.py \
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PhytonProjects\python_beginners_course-main\pythonProject\.idea\Testobot1488.py", line 43, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop = True)
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1104, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1179, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1141, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 149, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 92, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 7846, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    if self._test_message_handler(handler, message):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 7775, in _test_message_handler
    if not self._test_filter(message_filter, filter_value, message):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 7791, in _test_filter
    return message.content_type in filter_value
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\
> TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```